# Retrieve key value of multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

How do I reference the key of a multidimensional array?  Here is the array:

```
Array
(
[Nov 18, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => 3
        [I] => 1
    )
[Nov 22, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => 2
    )
)
```

and here is the foreach loop:

```
foreach($array as $date) { 
    foreach ($date as $k=>$v) {         
        // how to I reference the value of $billdate here ?
    }            
}
```

It is easy enough to reference the `$k` and `$v` inside the **inner** `foreach` loop, but how do I reference the date value contained in the **outer** `foreach` loop?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the key a value (apparently named `$billdate`) in the outer foreach loop.

```
foreach( $array as $billdate => $date) { 
    foreach( $date as $k => $v) {         
        echo $billdate; // Prints something like Nov 18, 2011
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `$billdate` is the key of each top-level array:

```
foreach ($array as $billdate => $date) {
    foreach ($date as $k => $v) {
        var_dump($billdate, $k, $v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get array keys by this way

```
print_r(array_keys(array_shift($array)));
```